# How to use ssh port forwarding to make a tcp connection to an remote application?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have an application running on port xxxx on a server. I can login to the server using the ip and a port yyyy like this

```
ssh user@ip -p yyyy
```

I need to create a tcp connection to the application running on port xxxx.
I did something like this

```
ssh -nNT -L <localport>:ip:xxxx user@ip -p yyyy
```

However, while the local application does connect to the local port, the messages never reach the remote app.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `-L <localport>:127.0.0.1:<remoteport>` in your command. The IP address used in the tunneling is from the point of view of the remote host. So, here you are telling SSH to forward local port `<localpost>` to `<remoteport>` on the localhost interface on the remote host.